# Semantic analysis of tweets

Tags: twitter, semantics, semantic-analysis

I have know how to communicate with twitter and how to retrieve tweets but I am looking for further working on these tweets.

I have two categories food and sports. Now I want to categorize tweets into food and sports. Can anyone please suggest me how to categorize on basis of computer algorithm?

regards
Gaurav

Comment: Please can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing some work recently with Latent Dirichlet Allocation. The general idea is that documents contain words that are generated from topics. What you could try doing is loading a corpus of documents **known** to be about the topics you are interested in, update with the tweets of interest, and then select tweets that have strong probabilities for the same topics as your known documents.

I use R for LDA (package:topicmodels and package:lda), but I think there are some prebuilt python tools for this too. I would probably steer away from trying to write your own unless you have a solid grounding in Bayesian statistics.

Here's the documentation for the topicmodels package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/vignettes/topicmodels.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that a set of algorithm could possibly categorize tweets in open domain. In other words I don't think a set of rules can possibly categorizes open domain tweets. You need to parse tweets into a semantic representation customized for the categorization.